# Clash between `scheduled_publish_time` and `tags` on Facebook graph API /page/feed post endpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can make a scheduled post fine.

I can make a post with tags to users fine.

If I try and do both together the response I get from facebook is "(#100) Invalid parameter"

Here's the code:

```
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id'                => FB_APP_ID,
        'app_secret'            => FB_APP_SECRET,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9'
    ]);

    //Post property to Facebook
    $linkData = [
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
        'message' => 'Test',
        'place' => 3333333333333333,
        'tags' => [55555555],
        'published' => false,
        'scheduled_publish_time' => 1498580000
    ];


    try {
        $response = $fb->post('/mypageid/feed', $linkData, FB_APP_ACCESS_NON_EXPIRES);
```

Any ideas?  There's no documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/page/feed that suggests these two properties shouldn't work together, and common sense doesn't immediately suggest a reason that they wouldn't.

Comment: So you already know _for sure_ that _all_ those users will be at _that_ place at _that_ time in the future …? Because otherwise, you should not be tagging them in the first place.

Comment: Well, no.  I know that they were at that place at a time in the past, and that I want the post telling that story to appear on users' feeds at a time in the future, that's not unusual is it?

Comment: Well then you should rather be backdating the post.

Comment: "(#100) Cannot make posts that are both unpublished and backdated"

Comment: I note that you said "rather", and I tried both instead.  You can see what I'm doing, I want to schedule a post to happen at a "popular" time in people's news feeds, about a story from a time a few hours/days in the past.  And linked to some facebook users that will find it interesting and may help me along the way by sharing the post.  Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: _“I want to schedule a post to happen at a "popular" time in people's news feeds”_ – this is one of the things were you should simply ask yourself, _“what would happen, if everyone started doing that?”_ ... that often helps to identify _bad ideas_ quite easily.

Comment: Well, to a degree I agree, but on the other hand the functionality to schedule posts IS there...